# What is the term for passing an eluate back through an adsorption column?

Tags: terminology

In my experiment I am passing a solution through an adsorption column, collecting the eluate, then passing the eluate back through the same column.

Is there a concise term which describes this process?

Comment: reapply the eluate to the column?

Comment: *Why* are you doing this?

Comment: @Karl The solution effectively is influent, and the adsorption column removes a pollutant from it. The eluate (i.e. effluent), when passed back through the same column, further decreases the pollutant's concentration. Therefore I'm trying to find a term to describe the process.

Answer (score 2):

This process is similar to re-cycling chromatography or recycling HPLC. In a more strict sense, it does not do any good, at least theoretically, if you keep on recycling all the eluate and transfer it back to the column.

What makes more sense is that you collect fractions and choose certain fractions for recycling.

Comment: Indeed.  It is like to perform multiple chromatography columns. Differently phrased and at least changing the second column is not too unusual.